# DOM parser in android

Tags: android, domparser

Tried to parse an xml file in res/xml using the following code.But when launches the project it shows an exception "there is no such file/directory".Is any error in the code?
Give me an answer immediately.Thanks in advance.

```
 try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder=docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        *Document doc=docBuilder.parse(new File("project_data.xml"));*
        NodeList projects=doc.getElementsByTagName("PROJECTDESC");
        for(int i=0;i<projects.getLength();i++)
        {
            Element project=(Element)projects.item(i);
            ProjectData projectdata=new ProjectData(null, null, null, null, null, null);

            projectdatas.add(projectdata);
            projectdata.setProject(project.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            projectdata.getProject();
        }
    }
catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: "+t.toString(), 4000).show();
    }
```

XML FILE IS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Results>
    <Row>
        <PROJECTID>1000</PROJECTID>
        <PROJECTDESC>ERP Tool</PROJECTDESC>
        <MANAGER>John Jakes</MANAGER>
        <SPONSOR>Gregory Mallor</SPONSOR>
        <STARTDATE>02-01-2010</STARTDATE>
        <PLANNEDCOMPDATE>06-21-2010</PLANNEDCOMPDATE>
        <PROBABLECOMPDATE>06-30-2010</PROBABLECOMPDATE>
        <STATUS>Active</STATUS>
        <PLNRSK>59.5065</PLNRSK>
        <EPLRSK/>
        <EPRRSK/>
        <BDTRSK/>
        <ACTUALCOMPDATE/>
        <MILESTONETOLERANCE>2</MILESTONETOLERANCE>
        <ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>1</ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>
        <WORKFLOWID>10002</WORKFLOWID>
        <CREATED>02/10/2010 16:20:43 PM</CREATED>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <PROJECTID>1001</PROJECTID>
        <PROJECTDESC>CMS Implementation</PROJECTDESC>
        <MANAGER>Florence Marie</MANAGER>
        <SPONSOR>Gregory Mallor</SPONSOR>
        <STARTDATE>02-11-2010</STARTDATE>
        <PLANNEDCOMPDATE>02-16-2010</PLANNEDCOMPDATE>
        <PROBABLECOMPDATE>02-17-2010</PROBABLECOMPDATE>
        <STATUS>Open</STATUS>
        <PLNRSK/>
        <EPLRSK/>
        <EPRRSK/>
        <BDTRSK/>
        <ACTUALCOMPDATE/>
        <MILESTONETOLERANCE>1</MILESTONETOLERANCE>
        <ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>1</ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>
        <WORKFLOWID>10004</WORKFLOWID>
        <CREATED>02/10/2010 17:07:14 PM</CREATED>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <PROJECTID>1002</PROJECTID>
        <PROJECTDESC>Key Account Manager Recruiting</PROJECTDESC>
        <MANAGER>Florence Marie</MANAGER>
        <SPONSOR>John Jakes</SPONSOR>
        <STARTDATE>02-11-2010</STARTDATE>
        <PLANNEDCOMPDATE>02-13-2010</PLANNEDCOMPDATE>
        <PROBABLECOMPDATE>02-13-2010</PROBABLECOMPDATE>
        <STATUS>Open</STATUS>
        <PLNRSK/>
        <EPLRSK/>
        <EPRRSK/>
        <BDTRSK/>
        <ACTUALCOMPDATE/>
        <MILESTONETOLERANCE>1</MILESTONETOLERANCE>
        <ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>1</ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>
        <WORKFLOWID>10009</WORKFLOWID>
        <CREATED>02/10/2010 17:07:18 PM</CREATED>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <PROJECTID>1003</PROJECTID>
        <PROJECTDESC>Fast Food Regional Market Analysis</PROJECTDESC>
        <MANAGER>John Jakes</MANAGER>
        <SPONSOR>Florence Marie</SPONSOR>
        <STARTDATE>02-12-2010</STARTDATE>
        <PLANNEDCOMPDATE>02-16-2010</PLANNEDCOMPDATE>
        <PROBABLECOMPDATE>02-16-2010</PROBABLECOMPDATE>
        <STATUS>Open</STATUS>
        <PLNRSK/>
        <EPLRSK/>
        <EPRRSK/>
        <BDTRSK/>
        <ACTUALCOMPDATE/>
        <MILESTONETOLERANCE>2</MILESTONETOLERANCE>
        <ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>1</ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>
        <WORKFLOWID>10010</WORKFLOWID>
        <CREATED>02/10/2010 17:07:22 PM</CREATED>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <PROJECTID>1004</PROJECTID>
        <PROJECTDESC>ss</PROJECTDESC>
        <MANAGER>John Jakes</MANAGER>
        <SPONSOR>Gregory Mallor</SPONSOR>
        <STARTDATE>02-11-2010</STARTDATE>
        <PLANNEDCOMPDATE>02-16-2010</PLANNEDCOMPDATE>
        <PROBABLECOMPDATE>02-17-2010</PROBABLECOMPDATE>
        <STATUS>Open</STATUS>
        <PLNRSK/>
        <EPLRSK/>
        <EPRRSK/>
        <BDTRSK/>
        <ACTUALCOMPDATE/>
        <MILESTONETOLERANCE>1</MILESTONETOLERANCE>
        <ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>1</ACTIVITYTOLERANCE>
        <WORKFLOWID>10080</WORKFLOWID>
        <CREATED>06/27/2010 19:16:26 PM</CREATED>
    </Row>
</Results>
```

Comment: Yes Sir, answer will be given immediatly...  Try to be a little more polite in your questions. We are all doing this voluntary.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception it gives you is "there is no such file/directory", then your error is with the location/name of the `project_data.xml` file. Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) resource for more information on file storage in Android... your xml file is likely not where you expect it is.

Answer (score 1):

Create your *res\raw* xml file and then use:

```
Resources res = getResources();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.file);

Document doc=db.parse(new InputSource(is));
```